# linkedin button dynamic rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, share, linkedin-api

How to render linkedin button in a dynamic way? e.g. writing the "<script type='in/share'></script>" at runtime or after the page has finished loading. I already tested on writing it or appending it in the body tag using jquery but it doesn't work. 
I'll appreciate any help. thanks.

Comment: here's the code : $('#div_tag_id').html('<script type='in/share'></script>');

Comment: You need to use proper `<>` and `type='in/share'` is not correct `script` syntax, is it? Where is the LinkedIn JS file located?

Comment: oh! my mistake,the wrapper quotes is supposed to be double quotes, typo error, the js file is in the footer part : <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js"></script>, I also tried to append the linkedin js file after the share button script, but same thing happend.

Answer (score 9):

For anyone still wondering how to do this, after you load your

```
<script type="IN/Share"></script> //Don't forget other attributes
```

Just call IN.init() in your javascript and it will render the buttons.

The Developer guide does say something about using undocumented functions, but this forum post on the developer site:

https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/3-problems-share-button

As stated by Eugene O'Neill (Web Developer for LinkedIn)

> 1) IN.Parse() and IN.Init() are here to stay. While we do employ the policy that any undocumented methods may or may not be supported indefinitely, these two are uniquely crucial to the functionality of the framework. The amount of work it would require to remove IN.Parse()... I don't even want to think about it ;). IN.Init() is our preferred method for loading the framework asynchronously and won't be going anywhere. Feel free to use either method.

Comment: I was still wondering how to do this, thank you :)

Also I wanted to add that it seems that you need to actually use the HTML data-* attribs to configure the button, modifying the dataset property of the DOM element does not get the job done.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I am doing it with jQuery. I just call the `linkedInShare` function when I want that share widget to load.

```
function linkedInShare() {
    $.getScript('http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js', function() { 
      $('.something').append('<script type="IN/Share" data-counter="top"></script>');
    });
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Genius. Sahas, if you're still about, could you help advise how to modify this for multiple LinkedIn buttons? I'm getting duplicate script call errors with getScript(). Thanks